# AlertDialog being trimmed in Android Pie

Tags: java, android

I have an app which gets the data from my web server's database and displays it into an AlertDialog, the app works fine on Android 8 (Oreo) and below but on Android 9 (Pie), the Dialog is being trimmed, essentially hiding the data that was fetched.

I have tried using the AlertDialogBuilder but still the same issue, I'm new to Android development and would appreciate a detailed explanation.

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String destination = strings[0];
        String query_url = "http://prateekrawat.000webhostapp.com/query.php";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(query_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("destination", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(destination, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();


            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

            String line = "";
            String result = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                result = result + "\n" + line;
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Buses");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="717dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Enter Destination"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.846" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="214dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="177dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:onClick="Submit"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Demo Images**

[image: Android Pie]
[image: Android Oreo]

[AlertDialog on Pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA0k9.jpg)

[AlertDialog on Oreo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zO5Y.jpg)

Comment: Please post your layout file as well

Comment: Also, show us how the `AlertDialog` works as intended when on Oreo

Comment: Added layout file @Leo also the image on Oreo

Answer (score 1):

try creating custom Dialog Style and add with and height in percentage.

**min_with_minor is**:

> The platform's desired minimum size for a dialog's width when it is
>   along the minor axis (that is the screen is portrait). This may be
>   either a fraction or a dimension.

**Min_witdh_major is:**

> The platform's desired minimum size for a dialog's width when it is
>   along the minor axis (that is the screen is portrait). This may be
>   either a fraction or a dimension.

try below Example.

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">

    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">80%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">80%</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMinor">80%</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMajor">80%</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ubp_bg_white_rect</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFC107</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">#4CAF50</item>

</style>


 AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
        myAlert.setTitle("Title");
        myAlert.setMessage("1298201");
        myAlert.show();
```

Below is Sample Result for Oreo :

[image: Oreo Result]

Below is sample result for Pie;

[image: Pie Result]

Comment: Tried it, still facing the same issue, the AlertDialog gets trimmed right after the title.

Comment: are you adding style in AlertDialog.?

Comment: Yes @Atif AbbAsi

Comment: are you sure you are getting both details.?

Comment: Yes I'm getting both details. style.xml
 <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">80%</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">80%</item>
        <item name="windowFixedHeightMinor">80%</item>
        <item name="windowFixedHeightMajor">80%</item>

Comment: The code works when you use static text, but in my app I'm using dynamic text which is being fetched from my web server, so the message field is still being trimmed there. 
You can test the app on [GitHub](https://github.com/prateekraawat1/bus-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/lnctbus/BackgroundWorker.java)
It doesn't have the latest changes but can still reproduce the issue.

Comment: @PrateekJain if its working fine with static text then you must be getting null data from server side.. thats why its getting trim post your logs

Comment: I thought of that and tried to print the data I'm getting from server somewhere else, but I'm getting the data from the server and can print it normally, it has something to do with AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to style, please create custom style and put there it will work fine.

```
 <style name="MyAlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/alertDialogBackground</item>
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/alertDialogBackground</item>
 </style>

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                getActivity(), R.style.MyAlertDialogTheme);
```

Comment: Still the same issue, the AlertDialog is still trimmed.